# pgfplots - plot a "flat" csv list of y-coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Are there key-value args that would allow me to plot a "flat" csv list of y-values in an axis? I'd rather not set a table then transpose it.

eg:  `\addplot table[header=false,x expr=\coordindex, y index=0, something else...]{3,2,1,2,3};`

```
\documentclass[11pt,parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\RequirePackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[clip limits=true, enlarge x limits=-1, enlarge y limits=-1]
        \addplot table[header=false,x expr=\coordindex, y index=0] {  % this works
            1
            2
            3
            2
            1
        };
        \addplot table[header=false,x expr=\coordindex, y index=0, % anything here to get the bottom string to work?
            ]{3,2,1,2,3};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `row sep` option, used to define what delimits rows in a table, has two options, either `newline` which is the default, or `\\`. The latter lets you do

```
\addplot table[header=false,x expr=\coordindex, y index=0,row sep=\\]{3\\2\\1\\2\\3\\};
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[clip limits=true, enlarge x limits=-1, enlarge y limits=-1]
        \addplot table[header=false,x expr=\coordindex, y index=0] {  % this works
            1
            2
            3
            2
            1
        };
        \addplot table[header=false,x expr=\coordindex, y index=0,row sep=\\
            ]{3\\2\\1\\2\\3\\};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Too bad you can't set row sep to something arbitrary like comma `row sep=comma`

Comment: @likethevegetable You can always add a feature request at https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues